# Why the slot function cannot insert text even if it's successfully called

Tags: c++, qt, text, qscintilla

I'm writing a code editor in Qt with QScintilla.

I want to automatically complete the back brackets when I enter the front brackets. So that I connect the `cursorPositionChanged(int, int)` signal to `complete_braces()` slot and the connection works. But the `insert()` statement doesn't work even if the slot function is called.

- This is for a Windows 10 PC, running Qt 5.13.0(MinGW 7.3.0 32-bit), Qt Creator 4.9.2, QScintilla 2.11.2.
- The connection of signal and slot works because the `qDebug()` statement output correctly.
- When I connect a toolbar button trigger to the slot function and push the button. The back brace is placed correctly.
- The `insert(QString)` function works when I call it in normal functions.

**Header:**

```cpp
/* codeeditor.h */
class CodeEditor : public QsciScintilla
{
    Q_OBJECT
...

public slots:
    void complete_brackets();
...
};
```

**Code:**

```cpp
/* codeeditor.cpp */
CodeEditor::CodeEditor()
{
...
    // Slots
    connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()),
            this, SLOT(complete_brackets()));
...
}
...
void CodeEditor::complete_brackets()
{
    int line, index;
    getCursorPosition(&line, &index);
    if (text(line)[index] == '(')
    {
        qDebug() << "Get a bracket"; // This statement works.
        insert(QString(")")); // This statement doesn't work.
    }
}
...
```

I expected the `insert(QString)` function in the slot function to be called correctly, but it doesn't.

How can I do to make the insert statement effective or, is there any other method to auto complete the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `QsciScintilla` does not allow adding text in the slot connected to the `textChanged` signal, a possible solution is to add it a moment later using a `QTimer::singleShot()`:

```cpp
void CodeEditor::complete_brackets(){
    int line, index;
    getCursorPosition(&line, &index);
    if (text(line)[index] == '(')
        QTimer::singleShot(0, [this, line, index](){
          insert(")");
          setCursorPosition(line, index+2);
        });
}
```

On the other hand it is recommended that you use the new connection syntax:

```cpp
connect(this, &QsciScintilla::textChanged, this, &CodeEditor::complete_brackets);
```

Comment: It works, thank you! However, when I use the new connection syntax, an error will occur that `"QObject::connect: signal not found in CodeEditor"`, but the old connection syntax works well. I don't know why it happened.